# Merge [using] into [using-statement] or vice versa?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both have absolutely similar wiki entries:

> In the C# language, the using keyword is employed in two different contexts, as a Directive and a Statement.

and

> It takes an expression that evaluates to an IDisposable. After that it executes an associated code block. Once the code block exits(both with normal and exceptional exits) it disposes the result of the original expression.

I think existence of both, [using](/questions/tagged/using) (463) and [using-statement](/questions/tagged/using-statement) (184), makes no sense.

Comment: I would vote to keep `using` - it makes no sense in any other way than being the language keyword/directive so there should be no confusion.

Comment: @slugster: On other hand most of such tags (language syntax keyword related) contains statement, block or another clarifying suffix. I'm really not sure which to choose from this two.